# Preselecting options of multiple selectbox, using Materialize css FW doesn't work

Tags: javascript, css, materialize

I'm using materialize css framework. When I'm printing multiple selectbox (`<select multiple>...`), preselected options (`<option selected...>`) won't render.
Browser however understand that some options are preselected, so they are send again, when the form is submited. Also because of the rendering issue i'm unable to manipulate with preselected options or select new ones.

Normal Selectbox works just fine.

Comment: Can you show your code for what you've done so far ?

Comment: I don't think it's neccesary, there is an error in the Select plugin that is intagrated into the materialize FW. I suggest I'll have to find it and correct it my self...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add onchange event to field and reset the values by accessing all the (li) children. If you see carefully. Multi select uses UL and a text field for value storing and keeps class "Active" for li. And append this code after .material select since check boxes are initialized after that

you can try following in

```
function change_materialize_multiple_Select(id_of_select)
{
    var newValuesArr = [],
            select = $(id_of_select),
            ul = select.prev();
        ul.children('li').toArray().forEach(function (li, i) {
            if ($(li).hasClass('active')) {
                newValuesArr.push(select.children('option').toArray()[i].value);
            }
        });
        select.val(newValuesArr);   
}
```